# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project: Command execution failed

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans

I create a maven java project in Netbeans with external maven. Maven version is 3.3.9, jdk1.7.0.45. Netbeans 7.4.  The project is built successfully, but run fail with following error. is it because of the wrong version of exec-maven-plugin? could someone tell me how to solve this problem? thanks advanced

```
--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ owlapitest2 ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\java project\owlapitest2\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ owlapitest2 ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ owlapitest2 ---
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(J)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI.<clinit>(IRI.java:318)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLFacet.<init>(OWLFacet.java:71)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLFacet.<clinit>(OWLFacet.java:39)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype$Category.<clinit>(OWL2Datatype.java:270)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype.<clinit>(OWL2Datatype.java:38)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryInternalsImplNoCache.<clinit>(OWLDataFactoryInternalsImplNoCache.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:259)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:259)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:61)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createInjector(OWLManager.java:89)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.instatiateOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:97)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:58)
    at com.mycompany.owlapitest2.App.main(App.java:19)

BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 5.371 s
Finished at: 2016-01-21T20:51:15+08:00
Final Memory: 9M/23M

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project owlapitest2: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

---

```
pom.xml 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>owlapitest2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>owlapitest2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>classworlds</groupId>
      <artifactId>classworlds</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-settings</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

```
package com.mycompany.owlapitest2;

import java.io.File;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.SimpleIRIMapper;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws OWLOntologyCreationException
    {
         OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

        // Load an ontology from the Web
        IRI iri = IRI.create("http://acrab.ics.muni.cz/ontologies/swrl_tutorial.owl");
        OWLOntology personOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(iri);
        System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + personOntology);

        // Remove the ontology so that we can load a local copy.
        manager.removeOntology(personOntology);

       // We can also load ontologies from files. Create a file object that points to the local copy
        File file;
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\zyy\\ontologies\\reference ontologies\\pizza.owl");

        // Load the local copy
        OWLOntology localPizza = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
        System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + localPizza);

        // Remove the ontology again so we can reload it later
         manager.removeOntology(personOntology);

        // When a local copy of one of more ontologies is used, an ontology IRI mapper can be used
        // to provide a redirection mechanism. This means that ontologies can be loaded as if they
        // were located on the Web. In this example, we simply redirect the loading from
        // http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl to our local copy above.
         manager.addIRIMapper(new SimpleIRIMapper(iri, IRI.create(file)));

       // Load the ontology as if we were loading it from the Web (from its ontology IRI)
          IRI pizzaOntologyIRI = IRI.create("http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl");
          OWLOntology redirectedPizza = manager.loadOntology(pizzaOntologyIRI);

          System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + redirectedPizza);
          System.out.println(" from: " + manager.getOntologyDocumentIRI(redirectedPizza));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the part of the POM configuring `exec-maven-plugin`? Or your whole POM?

Comment: there is no configuring about exec-maven-plugin in POM, should it be configured automatically? maybe it is included in some other dependency?

Comment: How are you invoking Maven? What is the command you are running?

Comment: I am not very clear what you mean. The command is "run project". and the project itself is a maven project.

Comment: I mean what is the Maven command you are running? Something like `mvn ...`.

Comment: Why do you have maven-plugins as dependencies that does not make sense at all...so remove those plugins from your dependency list...

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. My target is to run a java application, but many jars are missing. so I choose to create a maven java application in Netbeans to download and manage jar automatically.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stacktrace, the exception occored after `at com.mycompany.owlapitest2.App.main(App.java:19)` is invoked, so it is likely not a problem of maven, but a problem within you application.

According to the Exception, it looks like you have code that is complied for an other version of Guava then you have in your classpath while runtime.

Comment: then how to correct the version of Guava or other solution? I never set Guava manually.